# Is it possible to have two images in a single frame in motion jpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mjpeg

I have a quick time video file, video stream is in motion jpeg format, I extract every frame in the file with

> ffmpeg -i a.mov -vcodec copy -f image2 %d.jpg

I found that in every jpeg file, there are actually two `FFD8` marker, which means there are actually **two** images in one single jpeg file.

Is this correct? Is the file interlaced? Anything special need to pass to codec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, motion Jpeg supports interlaced format. If the jpeg file is half of the full video size, will mean that the mov is interlaced, and you cannot use `-vcodec copy` to extract the frames. Try `ffmpeg -deinterlace` or use **yadif** filter.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! My task is to decode this video on android with ffmpeg, the decoding process is split across a long process, finally the decoded image is just half the height told by ffprobe. I've been trying to figure out what may be missing but with no luck. Any suggestion on what to check?

Comment: I would say, if the decoded image is half height, this smells of interlaced video.

Comment: Yelp, problem solved, setting width and height in codec context as the parser told you, then the decoded image height is correct.